# GDI+ Creating filled CustomLineCap

Tags: c++, gdi+

I'm trying to build custom line caps in GDI+ (C++), and I can't get it to draw a filled cap, while unfilled caps draw fine.

I set up a closed polygon path, create a CustomLineCap with the path as the first parameter (fillPath parameter), and call SetCustomStartCap on the pen:

```
std::vector<Gdiplus::Point> pathPoints =
    {
        Gdiplus::Point(20,0),
        Gdiplus::Point(0,20),
        Gdiplus::Point(-20,0),
        Gdiplus::Point(20,0)
    };

Gdiplus::GraphicsPath path;
path.AddPolygon(&pathPoints[0], 4);

Gdiplus::CustomLineCap startCap(&path, nullptr);
Gdiplus::CustomLineCap endCap(nullptr, path.Clone());

m_Pen.SetCustomStartCap(&startCap);
m_Pen.SetCustomEndCap(&endCap);
```

I've read comments that it might have to do with the point order, or if the path is definitely closed. I've tried having the points both clockwise and counter-clockwise, but it didn't seem to help.

Can anyone spot if I'm doing something obviously wrong, or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the order of the points, I think there's also a requirement that the shape must intersect the negative y-axis, that is the line itself. So if you create your polygon like this

```
std::vector<Point> pathPoints =
{
    Gdiplus::Point(20,-1),
    Gdiplus::Point(0,19),
    Gdiplus::Point(-20,-1)
};
```

then you'll have a line cap with the desired shape and size, but it will overlap the line a bit.

Alternatively, if you want arrowheads specifically, take a look at [AdjustableArrowCap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluslinecaps/nl-gdipluslinecaps-adjustablearrowcap). Just set the isFilled property to TRUE and you're good to go. Or you can just use Pen's SetStartCap/SetEndCap methods with the LineCapArrowAnchor parameter, but then you probably can't customize your arrow.